# Need to convert duplicate column elements to a unique element in R

Tags: r

I need to convert the table A to table B. How can I do that using R?

**TABLE A**

```
Y 10
Y 12
Y 18 
X 22 
X 12
Z 11
Z 15
```

**TABLE B**

```
X 22 12
Y 10 12 18
Z 11 15
```

Comment: table B is not a table, and probably you have the letters mixed up.

Comment: the best you can do is get a list: `tapply(tb$value,tb$name,function(x)x)`, where `tb` is the your table A with 1st and 2nd columns named `name` and `value`.

Comment: yeah its not a table but I need the answer in 2 columns, first one should have the alphabets and the second one should have the corresponding values either in comma separated or tab delimited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what @mpiktas proposed, but using `aggregate`

```
# Construct the data frame
let <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Z", "Z")
num <- c(10, 12, 18, 22, 12, 11, 15)

df <- data.frame(let, num)

# Aggregate data by the first column.
# Do not apply any transformation to the data (use the identity function)
ag <- aggregate(df$num, FUN=identity, by=list(let))
# Find the line with maximum number of elements
maxlen <- max(sapply(ag$x, length)))
# Transform the list to a matrix
res <- t(sapply(ag$x, function(x){c(x, rep(NA, maxlen-length(x)))}))
row.names(res) <- ag[,1]
```

Outputs:

```
1> res
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
X   22   12   NA
Y   10   12   18
Z   11   15   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the possible solution with taking a clarification in comment in mind, but still I think that the question is invalid as it stands.

```
##This gives the table A with both columns in character, which we will use
df<-rbind(c("Y",10),c("Y",12),c("Y",18),c("X",22), c("X",12), c("Z",11), c("Z",15))
> df
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "Y"  "10"
[2,] "Y"  "12"
[3,] "Y"  "18"
[4,] "X"  "22"
[5,] "X"  "12"
[6,] "Z"  "11"
[7,] "Z"  "15"

##break the table into the list
l <-tapply(df[,2],df[,1],function(l)l)

##calculate the maximum length of the list element
n <- max(sapply(l,length))

##pad the elements of the list with empty strings
tbB<-t(sapply(l,function(x){res <- rep("",n);res[1:length(x)]<-x;res}))
> tbB
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
X "22" "12" ""  
Y "10" "12" "18"
Z "11" "15" ""  

##Comma separated file 
write.table(tbB,file="tableB.csv",quote=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",")


##Tab delimited 
write.table(tbB,file="tableB.txt",quote=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

If we read the table A from the file, then `df` is a data.frame with first column a `factor` and second column `numeric` (this is a default R behaviour). To apply the code above it is necessary to transform the columns to `character`:

```
df <- sapply(df,as.character)
```

Comment: Thanks mpiktas! As you said the question was not correct in the way I wanted, I agree with you but you answer is what I needed.Thanks again

Comment: @Jana, you're welcome. If this is the answer you need I suggest you accept it, this is how this site works. Look at the faq how to do that. You might want to accept answers to your other questions.

Comment: @Jana: click on the checkmark just below the vote up/down buttons.

Comment: @Jana, you might also want to read the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). It gives a pretty good summary how this site works.